# Mixing two custom components javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have modified the structure to create a simple example of the problem I am facing, which can be easily reproduced. I am attempting to combine two custom components - one is a custom button and the other is an hbox that contains the custom button.

The Java code and its corresponding fxml for the custom button are as follows:

```
    public class Custom_Button extends Button {
    public Custom_Button() {
    super();
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/eu/mylib/libraries_custom_/custom_button/Custom_Button.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                           }
```

FXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>


    <fx:root prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="168.0" stylesheets="@Custom_Button.css" text="RED" type="javafx.scene.control.Button" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    </fx:root>
```

now the second component :

java code:

```
public class Custom_Pick extends HBox {
public Custom_Pick() {
    super();
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/eu/mylib/libraries_custom_/custom_pick/Custom_Pick.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                        }
```

FXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <?import eu.mylib.libraries_custom_.custom_button.Custom_Button?>
        <fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <Custom_Button></Custom_Button>
        </fx:root>
```

I'll try to explain this as best as I can. Both components seem to work fine when I launch an app that contains them. However, my main issue is with Scene Builder. The first component is displayed correctly, which means it has a visual representation in Scene Builder. But the second component, which contains the first component, only displays a blank pane, and I'm not sure why.

IMAGES :

[image: this is when openening the 2nd custom component fxml it renders correctly]

[image: the custom button after importing the library renders as intended]

[image: the custom pick (second component that contains the custom button) renders as a blank pane]

project structure :
[image]

Comment: Please improve the quality of your posts, by indenting code (an [IDE can usually assist with that](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html), though I fixed most issues [in an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78097468/8)), following Java naming conventions as requested for your previous post, and by using punctuation correctly ([A tool such as grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) can help with that).

Comment: It may be best to add a [mcve] in case somebody wants to try to reproduce this.

Comment: @jewelsea thank you for the feedback i tried my best to come up with an easy and understandable example

Answer (score 0):

looks like i didn't search much , because the answer is already written here
thank you and sorry for the trouble
[Scene Builder Nested Custom Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482659/scene-builder-nested-custom-nodes/50493549#50493549)